# If $A$ is infinite then $P(A)$ is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove in (ZF) that for all $A,a,b$ with $a\notin A$ and $b \notin P(A)$
if there is a bijection $f$ from $A$ to $A \cup \{a\}$ then there is one from $P(A)$ to $P(A) \cup \{b\}$.

What I do is construct $A' = A\setminus \{z\}$ where $f(z) = a$
and $g(x)= \{f|_{A'}(t)\mid t\in x\}$ if $z\notin x$ and $g(x)= \{f|_{A'}(t)\mid t\in x\}\cup b$ if $z\in x$

What I have to prove is that it is a bijection, but I can't seem to do the surjective bit.

Comment: Your function $g$ is not well-defined $-$ if $z\in x$, then $g(x)$ is not even an element of $P(A)\cup\{b\}$.

Comment: The title is quite simple to prove, as a finite set is one such that there is an injection from the set onto a set of the form $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. There's a trivial injection from $A\to P(A)$, i.e., $x\mapsto\{x\}$, and injections are closed under composition.

Comment: @TonyK the case for $z \in x$ the first part of the definition of $g$ is always a subset of $P(A)$ for every subset $x$ of $A$ and then adding $\{b\}$ doesn't break it

Comment: @yoloexpectz: take for instance $g(z)$. By your definition, this is $\{b\}$; but $\{b\}$ is not an element of $P(A)\cup\{b\}$, it is a _subset_ of $P(A)\cup\{b\}$.

Comment: @TonyK I see, then if I make it $g(x) = \{...\} \cup b$ that should fix it

Comment: Umm, no. $\{\ldots\}\cup b$ is also not an element of $P(A)\cup\{b\}$ if $\{\ldots\}$ is non-empty. You need a different approach.

Comment: There is an injection $i:\mathbb{N} \to A$, define the injection $1_*:\mathbb{N} \to 2^A$ by $i_*(n) = \{i(n)\}$.

Comment: @copper.hat: that works if your definition of an infinite set $A$ is that there exists an injection from $\Bbb N$ to $A$. But the OP is starting from the definition that there is a bijection from $A$ to $A\cup\{a\}$. These definitions are equivalent, but that takes some proving.

Comment: @TonyK you have a different approach?

Comment: I've edited for clarity. There was also a slight mistake in the original version: the second right parenthesis in "$P(A))$" should have been moved to the end of that paragraph, since what follows is still in the scope of the quantifier block "$\forall A\forall a\forall b$."

Comment: @TonyK: Since this is in ZF, not ZFC, the title and the first sentence are *not* equivalent. In ZF you can have an infinite set that is not in bijection to the set with an element added.

Comment: @celtschk: Before we start arguing at cross purposes, what is your definition of an infinite set?

Comment: @TonyK: An infinite set is one that is not in bijection to an $n$-element set with any $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @TonyK Being in bijection with a proper superset (or subset) is *Dedekind-infiniteness*; "infinite" on its own in the ZF context means what celtschk wrote. And there are other finiteness notions out there too.

Comment: @TonyK Their most recent comment gives a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll observe something a bit easier to visualize:

> Suppose $C$ is a set, $c\in C$, and $f$ is a bijection between $C$ and $C\setminus\{c\}$. Then there is a bijection from $P(C)$ and $P(C)\setminus\{\{c\}\}$.

*Proof*. We trivially have an injection $P(C)\setminus\{\{c\}\}\rightarrow P(C)$. To get an injection in the opposite direction, send an $X\subseteq C$ to $\{f(x): x\in X\}$. Now apply Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein. $\quad\Box$

Now, do you see how to prove that your statement is equivalent to the one I've made above? *(Hint: think of my $C$ as your $A\cup\{a\}$ ...)*

---

EDIT: while CSB is entirely explicit (and in particular doesn't require the axiom of choice) and an important thing to master, it's also unnecessary here; see ℋolo's comment below.

Comment: You don't need CSB, by let $g:P(C)→P(C)\setminus\{\{c\}\}$ be the identity for $x\ne\{y\}$ where $y∈C$, otherwise let $g(\{y\})=\{f(y)\}$

Comment: @ℋolo True, it's certainly not necessary and that's much clearer.